# node.js, node-mongodb-native, DRY connections?

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

I currently have the following code in every file under ./routes.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var config = require('../config/config');

var Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,

var server = new Server(config.DatabaseConfig.host, config.DatabaseConfig.port, {auto_reconnect: true});
db = new Db('test', server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Connected to 'test' database");
        db.collection('testcollection', {safe:true}, function(err, collection) {
        });
    }
});
```

Is there a way for me to open this connection in a central place? Is it even generally accepted to have each object have its own collection in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I open the database once in the main app entry point and don't call app.listen until the database connection is established.

`db.open(function(err) { if(!err) app.listen(3000); });`

Comment: The way I finally did it, is attaching db to app.db and `module.exports.app = app;`. This way this connection is available anywhere `app` is available.